# Calling base constructor without directly calling

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I have an "API" in which a user extends a base class the base class contains something like the following

```
class A {
    A();
    A(int, int);
}

class B : public A {
    B();
}
```

I would like to be able to call `B(int, int)` without actually setting up a constructor in B to call it so basically I would like to create sort of like a virtual method for the constructor so that its already set but can be overwritten. Is there any good way to do this or am I going to have to have them include a constructor that calls `A(int, int)`

Comment: `using A::A;` (inherited constructors)

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, you can use *inheriting constructors*:

```
class B : public A {
    using A::A;
    B();
}
```

This allows you to do the following:

```
B b(42, 42);
```

In C++03, you have to do it by hand:

```
class B : public A {
    B(int i, int j) : A(i,j) {}
    B();
}
```

Comment: Will any constructor in B, with matching declaration to one in A, shadow the one in A?

Comment: That's true, but once you define `B::B(int, int)`, you can't get around listing the base initializer explicitly.

Comment: @Kerrek: Which seems reasonable to me, as you wouldn't define `B::B(int, int)` if all you wanted it to do is to call `A::A(int, int)`

Comment: @Skeen Correct. So `B()` will hide `A()` in this example.

Comment: Do I have to do something like using A::A(int, int) or something cause I keep getting errors saying that there is no matching function for A(int, int)